# Intersection (p5.js)

Tags: intersection, p5.js

How do I check if a **circle** and a **rectangle** intersect in P5.js?

I'm working on this game, and I don't know how to check if the circle goes **through** the rectangle, or if it doesn't.

https://editor.p5js.org/AlexArek/sketches/rkoc4XA3m

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will get more help much more quickly if you show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something called **collision detection.**

There are a ton of resources on the internet, so I recommend googling something like "rectangle circle collision detection" for a bunch of results.

Another option to consider: you can usually get away with treating your circle as a rectangle and doing rectangle-rectangle collision detection. This approach is called [bounding box collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection#Axis-Aligned_Bounding_Box) and is very common in things like video games.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection. It's written for Processing, but the same ideas apply to P5.js.

I recommend you try something out and post a question along with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you have a more specific question. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
if(object1.collide(object2){
  console.log("Objects interesected");
}
```

Comment: This might work as .collide() is a built in function